# Вывод текста с "\n" из списка: не переносится на новую строку

Tags: python

**Текст в txt файле:**

```
It is a... \nof a page when looking at its layout
```

**Код:**

```
f = open('f.txt', 'r')
s_list = f.readlines()

current_quest = 0

print(s_list[current_quest])
```

**Вывод:**

```
It is a... \nof a page when looking at its layout
```

**Должен быть так:**

```
It is a... 
of a page when looking at its layout
```

Comment: Просто в файле у Вас *текст* `\n`, а не символ перевода строки, который при просмотре в файле был бы виден именно как превод строки (т.е. 2 строчки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну можно произвести замены типа

```
text = r'line1\nline2'
text = text.replace(r'\n', '\n')
```

чтобы заменить 2 символа `\n` на один символ, который означает перенос строки

а вообще используйте стандартные функции, которые позволяют декодировать эскейп последовательности

```
text = r'line1\nline2'

text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')
```